# Check if folder is a mounted remote filesystem

Tags: linux, shell-script, filesystems, mount

What is the best way (reliable, portable, etc.) to check if a given folder is on a mounted remote (nfs) filesystem within a shell script?

I am looking for a command that would look like:

```
chk-remote-mountpoint /my/path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As *Stephane* says "there is no universal Unix answer to that".

The best solution I have found to my question:

```
df -P -T /my/path/to/folder | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'
```

will return the filesystem type, for example: `nfs` or `ext3`.

The `-T` option **[is not](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html) standard**, so it may not work on other Unix/Linux systems...

According to *Gilles*' comment below: "This works on any non-embedded Linux, but not on BusyBox, *BSD, etc."

Comment: This works on any non-embedded Linux, but not on BusyBox, *BSD, etc. It's up to you to decide whether that's good enough.

Comment: Viewing `/etc/mtab` or results of `mount` instead of using `df` could do in some more cases.

Comment: @TNW or even `/proc/mounts`

Comment: Apparently, neither `mount`, nor `/etc/mtab`, not even `/proc/mounts` are standard so there is no guarantee on what may be found there...

Comment: This not work on OSX 10.8 as `-T` have a different meaning here

Comment: Just as reference: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=df+-P+-T+%2Fmy%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffolder+%7C+tail+-n+%2B2+%7C+awk+%27%7Bprint+%242%7D%27

Comment: what about the portability of `--output`? `df --output=fstype /my/path/to/folder | tail -1`

Comment: @Huafu [not standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html), not portable.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know - btw how/where you find out what is standard and/or portable?

Comment: @Huafu I use the [Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm).

Answer (score 19):

You could use GNU `stat`.

`%m` to find out the mountpoint.

```
$ stat --format=%m /usr/src/linux
/usr/src
```

`%T` (in file-system mode) to find out the name of the file system.

```
$ stat --file-system --format=%T /usr/src/linux
reiserfs
```

Thus you know that `/usr/src/linux`, on my system, is stored in a filesystem that is mounted on `/usr/src` and has the filesystem type `reiserfs`.

Also refer to `man stat` for further reference. It's a very versatile command, useful almost always when you need info about files and don't want to fall back to `grep | awk`wardness.

Comment: My version of `stat` does not have the `%m` option for `--format` (using Debian Squeeze, coreutils 8.5). So, I guess this solution is not very reliable.

Comment: I didn't believe it, but diff between coreutils 8.5 and 8.13 (debian wheezy) says you're right, though. Consider me very surprised :) squeeze is just too old :( err, too stable

Comment: from the coreutils changelog: `2010-08-27 <Aaron Burgemeister> stat: add %m to output the mount point for a file`. That's almost 3 years ago. Amazing that Debian still does not have this.

Comment: Even if Debian Squeeze was released on 2011-02-06, it [was frozen](http://www.debian.org/News/2010/20100806) on 2010-08-06, before this coreutils change... I'm rather looking for a "standard" solution possible if possible.

Comment: Well, you could just use the file-system %T command, if that works in old stat. If that doesn't work either and your version of stat does not provide the information you need, back to the awkward solutions it is.

Comment: Unfortunately `%T` doesn't work either, see [my comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem#comment-104600) on *Stephane Chazelas*' answer.

Comment: And unfortunately, the `stat` utility is [not standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html).

Comment: Thank you for posting this. In 2021, this answer is a lot more widely applicable than commenters in 2013 concluded.

Answer (score 9):

`mount -l` and use `grep`, `sed`, or `awk` to find the line that refers to the directory in question.

Comment: It looks complicated to figure out that `/my/path/to/the/directory` is actually something from the mountpoint `/my/path` with your answer. Maybe you can give some more details about the `grep`, `sed`, `awk` commands you suggest (a complete answer)?.

Comment: `mount -l | grep 'type nfs' | sed 's/.* on \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'` should give you a list of all nfs mountpoints on the system.

Comment: This can be combined with stat: `mount | fgrep "\`stat --printf=" on %m type" /var/log/\`". The `mount` command will print all mount points, in `<device> on <mountpoint> type <type>` format. To grep this, I have `stat --printf` generate the `on <mountpoint> type` part.

Comment: there are many local and remote filesystem mount types.  having a map of all of them may be challenging.  (for example is drvfs local or remote?)

Comment: Yes, but the question specifically asks about nfs: "mounted remote (nfs) filesystem"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no universal Unix answer to that.

One thing you can do, for a given file `/a/b/c/d` is walk up the path:

- /a/b/c/.
- /a/b/c/..
- /a/b/c/../..
- ...

... and do a `stat(2)` at each level, until the `st_dev` changes. Then you'll know where the mount point is. Then you can look up the canonical path of that mount point in `/etc/mtab` or in the output of `mount` to find out the file system type. Then finding out what is remote and what is not is going to be tricky especially for fuse-type ones. For instance, `nfs`, `cifs`, `fuse.sshfs`, `fuse.davfs` are obvious, but what about for instance `fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon` or `fuse.avfsd` that can have both network and non-network files?

Comment: Well, I'm using nfs here (edited my question). As for `stat(2)`, I think you are refering the C function, but I'm using shell. However, `st_dev` refers the to major and minor device ID (is that Linux specific?), and the shell command `stat(1)` has (non-standard) `%t` and `%T` with the `--format` options for respectively major and minor numbers, **but** it always returns "0" (local and nfs). I tried on Debian Squeeze and Lenny.

Comment: Are you trying this with or without the `--file-system` option?

Comment: @frostschutz Without. It has another meaning if used with `--file-system`.

Answer (score 2):

The "-l" to df(1) will fail with an error on non-local filesystems, so you can use this behavior to know if the filesystem is remote:

```
df -l /path 2> /dev/null | grep -q "File"
rc=$?
if [ "$rc" = "0" ]
then
   echo "local mount, do stuff"
fi
```

However, the `-l` option is [not standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html).

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @Totor why not? Granted, there are all sorts of other reasons why `df` would fail and that alone makes this a not very good answer, but it is trying to answer the question so I don't see why you'd call it "not an answer".

Comment: @terdon I agree. I didn't read carefully enough. Thank you for pointing this out. I'll edit and vote up. :)

Comment: This is basically the only one that works reliably on linux.

Answer (score 1):

`df /path` will tell you that `/path` is a mount point if it says that the mount point is not `/`.

Comment: The question refers to a **remote** mount point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `df -t` on Linux and `df -T` on BSD systems.

From [man df](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df):

> -t, --type=TYPE
>
> limit listing to file systems of type TYPE

```
if df -t nfs | grep -q /path/to/folder$; then
  # it is an NFS
fi
```

Comment: Pretty nice. However, and unfortunately, the `-t` option has a [different meaning](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html) in POSIX/SUS. So, using this option may provide inconsistent results in different versions on the tool/UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
df /me/path/to/folder
```

If the first field (the Filesystem) is in the format  host:/path
then you know it is NFS

So:

```
df /my/path/to/folder | awk 'NR==1{next};$1~/:[/]/{print "yes";exit(0)};{print "No";exit(1)}'
```

Now, put it in a bash file named "ifchk-remote-mountpoint".

Usage:

```
if ifchk-remote-mountpoint  /my/path/to/folder >/dev/null; then
    ...do something...
fi
```

or:

```
ISNFS=$(ifchk-remote-mountpoint  /my/path/to/folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine on CentOS 7.

1. Find the mount point of the required path (`/mnt/users/bbharati` in my case) with the below command:

`df -hk /mnt/users/bbharati`

```
Filesystem                                 1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
svm-dev-01-2048-lif:/expo_dev_users/users 6764573504 3540678720 3223894784  53% /mnt/svmdev01expodevusers
```

2. From the output of the above command, pick the value for the `Mounted on` field, and use that in the below command:

`mount -l | grep /mnt/svmdev01expodevusers`

```
svm-dev-01-2048-lif:/expo_dev_users/users on /mnt/svmdev01expodevusers type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=1.......)
```

You can see that in the output of the second command, type is `nfs`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`findmnt`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt) command should give you exactly the output you're looking for:

```
$ findmnt --output=FSTYPE -nfT /run/user/1000/kio-fuse-VBkDcY/sftp/hostname/my/path/to/folder
fuse.kio-fuse
```

The output is simply the filesystem type. In my case, I gave it a file which was mounted remotely in dolphin file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Umount the remote filesystem.
Put a strange file name in the mount destination.
Remount.
Check the presence of that file.
If it exists, the mount point is down.

Answer (score -2):

I would personally use `mountpoint` (very portable on Linux!):

```
NAME
       mountpoint - see if a directory is a mountpoint

SYNOPSIS
       mountpoint [-d|-q] directory
```

or `showmount` which is pretty much required to be installed on any system that actually mount `NFS` shares (part of `nfs-common` package):

```
NAME
       showmount - show mount information for an NFS server

SYNOPSIS
       showmount [ -adehv ] [ --all ] [ --directories ] [ --exports ] [ --help ] [ --version ] [ host ]
```

Another option would be someting like:

```
$ mount -l -t nfs | grep 'my mount point'
```

Comment: The `mountpoint` utility does not tell you if the mount point is remote. Moreover, remote filesystems are not limited to NFS filesystems. Finally, `mountpoint` is not standard (not in [this list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html)).

Comment: you specifically requested a tool on linux and NFS, `mountpoint` is standard in this case.

Comment: This does not answer my first point anyway.

Answer (score -3):

```
find . -type d -name nfs -exec mountpoint {} \; | grep not
```

will check all folders named 'nfs' if they're mounted

Comment: OP is not looking for folders named `nfs`.