# Test if a file is on NFS?

Tags: filesystems, files, nfs

Is there a simple test to determine if a file is on an NFS mount?  (Or maybe more generally, what type of filesystem a file lives on?)  I am imagining some ugly prefix matching against fstab...

Comment: You may be interested in [that answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `stat` on Linux at least:

```
stat -fc %T /path/to/the/file
```

It works for `nfs` and most common filesystems, but not for all of them.

Comment: Consider using `%t` instead in scripting because `%T` has documentation "file system type in human readable form" which suggests that the result may change depending on version of `stat` or kernel or OS release. On the other hand, `%t` always returns "file system type in hex" which I would assume is stable in the future, too.

Answer (score 3):

This is kinda random, but not terribly dirty:

```
df -TP /path/to/your/file | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

It will break if your filesystem name has spaces in it.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an answer in C, and this question from several years ago shows up as a first Google result, though it focuses on shell scripts, I think I will share my findings for anyone else who is looking.

As mentioned around this and related questions, there is no portable way.  Here are some non-portable ways in C to get filesystem type based on a filename (can be a mount point, or any file under the mount point):

## Linux

Use `statfs(2)` and compare `f_type` against the magic words in the manpage (eg. `NFS_SUPER_MAGIC`)

## macOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD

Use `statfs(2)` [or `statvfs(2)` on NetBSD], then the `f_fstypename` string.  (Will be `"nfs"` for NFS case.)

Other *BSDs and similar may have this, above are the ones I tested.

## Solaris

Use `stat(2)`; on Solaris `struct stat` has a `st_fstype` member. (Will be `"nfs"` for NFS case.  Optionally you can parse `/etc/dfs/fstypes` for a full list of remote filesystem types.)