# How can I determine if an NFS remote is exporting a directory?

Tags: rhel, directory, nfs, remote

In my script, I have several layers of statusing:

1. remote is available (ping)
2. remote NFS service is active
3. remote NFS is exporting a certain directory
4. remote NFS is mounted (mount)

For (2) and (3), I believe `rcpinfo` is the best bet.  For (2) though, I cannot figure out how to narrow my query to the NFS service without starting a subshell (which is not acceptable for this application).  For (3), I'm not sure this information is even available remotely (without `ssh`ing in, of course).

I'm working on RHEL 6 and have no access to programs that are not included in the standard distribution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For 3) you probably want to use `showmount -e remote_nfs_server` which shows if remote_nfs_server has exported anything.

And for 2) if you don't want to use a shubshell and know if the remote server runs NFSv3 or NFSv4 and if TCP or UDP, you could query for that specifically with rpcinfo:
`rpcinfo -u remote_nfs_server nfs 3`
for NFSv3 via UDP and
`rpcinfo -t remote_nfs_server nfs 4` for NFSv4 via TCP

For 4) you may want to look at [Check if folder is a mounted remote filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem)

---

Further information:

- [Remote procedure call tools | Managing NFS and NIS](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch13_03.htm)
- [NFS Diagnostic Tools | Managing NFS and NIS](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch14_01.htm)

Comment: `showmount -r remote` will tell me if `remote` is exporting *anything*, but is there any way for me to determine if `remote:/mnt/dir` is being exported without starting a subshell (i.e. a pipeline)?

Comment: ```showmount -e remote``` will tell you if ```remote``` has exported anything. ```showmount -r``` will only give you an error message as that option doesn't exist.

You could try to use shell substring matching to basically grep for a regular expression in the showmount output. Maybe have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619720/multiline-regexp-matching-in-bash

Comment: Or put the other way around, I don't know of any standalone command which can specifically query a remote NFS server for one particular mount, and I don't think that exists. Only other two viable ways would be to query the remote server locally via ssh (although even then there's no _reliable_ way to determine if a given directory is currently exported due to the stateless nature of NFS).  
Other approach could be to try to mount the NFS export from the client and check for the exit code and then the local mount and its contents.

Comment: My mistake with the `-r` option versus `-e` – that's what I meant :) The 'attempt approach' has been suggested before. I don't particularly like it, but it's looking like a real option.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `showmount -e <server>` for some aspects of #3.  When the exports are simple, it would at least suggest that a directory (or perhaps a parent of such a directory) is exported.

```
# showmount -e server
/export                               (everyone)
```

For #2, I'm not sure what you're looking for.  If you're using NFSv3, you'll be looking for at least mountd and nfs (and in some cases may want to confirm lock managers).  You could check for any explicitly with rpcinfo as you say.

```
# rpcinfo -t server mountd 3
program 100005 version 3 ready and waiting
```

Comment: `showmount -r remote` will tell me if `remote` is exporting *anything*, but is there any way for me to determine if `remote:/mnt/dir` is being exported without starting a subshell (i.e. a pipeline)?

Comment: That depends on the facilities at your disposal.  What is your script written in?  Why is starting a separate executable (showmount) less of a problem than starting another shell?

Comment: I'm writing my script in Python 2.6 and using the `subprocess` module.  I can set up a pipeline with it, but I'd rather not complicate the design that much.  I need to avoid starting a subshell to allow the script to be killed gracefully -- if it is killed, its child processes will be killed, but *not* the children of the child processes.  Thus, the subshell would be killed, but not the processes the subshell spawns.  I've also noted `rpcinfo` can take up to three minutes to return, which is the original basis for the no-subshell thing.  It's far too late to change that now, though.

Comment: Write a separate script that does what you need (like calls showmount, but takes an argument for directory and returns success/failure, and includes a timeout that is reasonable for your purposes), then call that script from your python.

Comment: I can promise you it's not as easy as you'd immediately think – when it's locked up so, `rpcinfo` does not respond to anything but SIGKILL (which is a misattribution – the OS obviously just kills the process).  At any rate, that would still start a shell to start `rpcinfo` – the underlying problem remains.

Comment: I think this is really a separate question from the NFS issue, it's about aspects of what you want to achieve from a python script.  Perhaps you should ask that separately.  But what is the purpose of getting this info?  Is it just for troubleshooting?  You could simply attempt the mount and handle failure.  Is it a big advantage to detect that it's not exported before issuing the mount?  For a down host, that could take some time.  But if it's just unexported, I'd expect immediate failure.

Comment: It truly is a separate issue – one that I've asked separately before (somewhere) to no great success or revelation. This script is part of a vast and (over-)complicated statusing network; I could create the mount and handle failure, but it would end up being an expensive step (since it would need to mount, unmount, and usually mount again).  It's why I have so many levels of statusing – to ensure as little work as possible is done twice.

Comment: @SeanAllred Luckily, you don't need to create a subshell or a pipeline to look at the output of a process. Use `output=subprocess.check_output(["showmount","-e",server])` and look through the `output` string for a line that starts with the directory or parent of a directory you want to know about.

Comment: @SeanAllred: This seems more of a case of the XY problem.
Maybe you should take a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.
Before investing any further time into that script, you better fix the NFS servers. Putting that much efforts into a script to check beforehand that much stuff for a basic task like this seems a clear indication for obvious underlying issues.   
What is your goal? If a mount is exported, mount it - and in case not, your script does what exactly? Only output the error messages for your 4 checks?

Comment: I'm very familiar with the XY problem; we get them all the time over at TeX.SX.  It may not look like it from my rep on this particular site, but I've been on SE for quite a while `:)`.  I do not have control over the NFS servers -- this is an extremely large and complicated system with multiple contracts for it -- I don't like it, but there is defensive code *everywhere*.  And actually -- *yes* that kind of granulated status is part of the design.  More accurately, it can (and should) return exit codes based on the mount status.

Answer (score 0):

List all pseudo root NFS-V4 export directories

```
ls /net/ip-addr-nfs-server
```

[Check out my answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187345/iptables-rules-for-nfs-server-and-nfs-client/27393897#27393897)

Comment: For a `/net` mount to work, the `/etc/auto.net` script must establish that the server has a corresponding export. This uses the `showmount` command. If the server only has NFSv4, it wont work (showmount displays `RPC: Program not registered`, and `/net/server` will just report `File not found`)