# How to dynamically re-mount a network share if it's there?

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab, automounting, shared-folders

Is there any way to automatically check if a network share is currently available or not, and if the state changed not only (un)mount it but perform any arbitrary other action? My best guess would be a cronjob, but maybe there's a better way for this.

Comment: I added the nfs tag on an assumption; remove or replace it if I’m wrong.

Comment: @JeffSchaller It can be NFS, it might as well be a Windows share or even e.g. sshfs

Answer (score 0):

You may use `autofs` and test if the mountpoint provides some data or remains empty or you can test the NFS share availability:

[unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176673/how-can-i-determine-if-an-nfs-remote-is-exporting-a-directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176673/how-can-i-determine-if-an-nfs-remote-is-exporting-a-directory)