# How to determine if an NFS mount is present, but the server is not running?

Tags: nfs

I'm trying to find out what NFS mounts are active / trying to connect to a server, where the server is not present at start up of the client computer.

Here is an example command which is called to mount the NFS directory, only IP and directories are changed, options are the same:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,soft,bg 192.168.1.178:/mnt/nfs_share /mnt/nfs_connection/
```

I can see it as soon as the connection is actually up with the solutions provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem), but none of these work when the server is not there yet. Or my linux-foo is not strong enough to understand what i'm seeing :)

Comment: Ah, of course! `ps -ef | grep mount` lead me straight to it. If you want you can post this as the answer :)

Comment: Easy internet points:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` would show you a completed mount, and as long as the server is down, you should see the `mount` command running in the background, trying to do its job.