# How to identify if a filepath is remote(network) or on removable media

Tags: linux, c

I have a C application which needs to check if a given filepath is local or remote/removable media.

I found an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem) which suggests using `statfs`. But it won't tell me if it is on USB

Plus, the `statfs` file type output has 100+ types :) And that post is dated 2013

Isn't there any simple way to do this programmatically, like `GetDriveType` function in Windows ?

I would really like to avoid any `grepping` from system utility outputs inside the C code. And have a portable way to do this as the users could be running this application on different distros

Comment: "removable" is a vague idea though. some might consider it a synonym to USB, some might consider whether the SCSI RMB bit is set to be the sole factor. I suppose you would probably want to dive into getting info (i.e. which bus type) from udev programatically, or maybe checking a bit in a SCSI INQUIRY response (like what `sg_inq` in sg3_utils does).

Comment: Ah !! By removable I mean USB, ISO disc etc.

Comment: You may also want to look into udisks2's code to see how it determines whether a drive is considered "removable" btw.

Comment: Will do, thanks. But will any of these be able to identify file paths ?

Comment: Why? I mean, what practical use do you have for that information?  It's out of scope for most apps (with exceptions like CD/DVD burning).  apps should focus on their purpose, and leave it up to users to decide where to store their files and on what - local drive, ramdisk, network mounts, removable drive, whatever   BTW, most programs I've seen that care about what/where/how a file is stored were probably written with the intention of being "helpful" but what they ended up doing was restricting the end-user to whatever ideas and technology the dev had available at the time.

Comment: The application accepts a `CACERT` file path to a CA certificate. I need to make sure that the CA path is local and not on a remote path or removable media.

Comment: Why? What purpose does that serve, other than to artificially restrict users to use-cases that you personally can imagine?   For example, some people might want to have their ca cert on a USB stick so they can yank it and put it somewhere secure, like in a safe, or with their lawyer.

Comment: What to do when a paranoid customer asks for this feature to be implemented in the application when it is mandated by their security compliance team :) One can argue that it should be done in their environment and not the application

Comment: Maybe you should simply be even more paranoid: forbid anything on a filesystem different from `/` or maybe `/home` (take reference from `-x` of `du` or `-xdev` of  `find`).

Comment: @TomYan, yes maybe. I think something like this can work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615464/how-to-get-device-name-on-which-a-file-is-located-from-its-path-in-c Check that '/' and the file path specified by the environment variable map to the same device