# Why does the 'chown' command does not work recursively using the '-R' flag for directories owned by the user nobody?

Tags: linux, permissions, chown

**System:** x86_64 Linux 5.13.19-2-MANJARO.

I have a weird directory in '~/.local/share/Trash/expunged' which contains a few directories owned by the user *nobody*. I tried to execute the following command as root:

```
rm -rf pathToWeirdDirectory
```

which yields in the following error message

> rm: cannot remove 'pathToWeirdDirectory': Value too large for defined data type

After changing the directory ownership using

```
chown me:me pathToWeirdDirectory
```

I finally succeeded to remove the directory. There are some more directories of this type with several subdirectories containing multiple files. I have tried to execute the following command:

```
chown -R me:me pathToSecondWeirdDirectory
```

which yields to the following error message:

> chown: cannot read directory 'pathToSeconWeirdDirectory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2': Permission denied

As far as I was concerned the '-R' flag changes ownerships recursively for the given directory, thus I created the following test case:

```
directory/
    file
    subdirectory/
    file2
```

owned by user *me*. I successfully changed its ownership using 'chown -R root:root directory' including all subdirectories and file as it was expected.

**Question:** Why does the 'chown' command does not work recursively using the '-R' flag for directories owned by the user *nobody*? Why is it not possible to delete files owned by the user *nobody* as *root*?

**Edit:** In response to the comments I would like to provide the full name of 'pathToSecondWeirdDirectory'.

> ~/.local/share/Trash/expunged/294376611/5e5a7b41-3df4-4b2f-b7ac-f57d09ed1823/.sage/matplotlib-1.5.1

Another example

> ~/.local/share/Trash/expunged/294376611/5e5a7b41-3df4-4b2f-b7ac-f57d09ed1823/.sage/R

**Edit 2:** After Marcus has given a great answer, I did some more debugging using the same technique. Chowning a single directory works as expected. Chowning using -R fails. I've compared the outputs and the are identical until the last few lines. Here are they:

*CHOWN*:

```
close(8)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "security", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
fchownat(AT_FDCWD, "security", 60202, 60202, 0) = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

*CHOWN -R*

```
close(8)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "startup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "startup", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2998, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2998
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "chown: ", 7)                  = 7
write(2, "cannot read directory 'startup'", 31) = 31
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Permission denied", 19)     = 19
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Why were there directories owned by nobody in the first place? That use should not own anything on a system. Also, I'm much more interested in what provoked the "Value too large for defined data type" error, which I've never seen before.

Comment: Please post an example of the weird names, do they have spaces in them or special characters by any chance?

Comment: I have no idea how these files were created or why its ownership is set to nobody. I have add an example of a full path.

Comment: My guess would be that the nobody:nobody results from the access of this location by networking, maybe samba or NFS, would this make any sense?  Who or what is sage in your environment ?  If they are a result of remote filesystem access, even root may not be able to change them from your system

Comment: This could be possible, but the possibility is very low, I am afraid. I had a Macintosh sharing some directories via NFS a (very, very) long time ago, but nothing related to SageMath. This could be some legacy from older systems. However, isn't it still weird that we can't we change the ownership recursively for this directories as root (or delete it)? The error message for 'rm' does also look unrelated (but obviously it is).

Comment: @DavidScholz weird for sure. Wait, can you run `type rm` for us? and if it's an executable with a path, `file /path/to/rm`?

Comment: The first yields to 'rm is /usr/bin/rm', the second yields to '/usr/bin/rm: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=5d1d8b77d21f9362855e93f8cff5fc685127a26f, for GNU/Linux 4.4.0, stripped'.

Comment: Are they real files or symbolic links (ls -l)?  Does the output of mount show anything mounted relevant to these locations?  To me this really looks like the files are on a network drive or are being accessed over the network which is why your root commands are failing, when nfs (maybe only v4) filesystems are mounted they can present the ownership as nobody:nobody, but in reality this is not the real owner on the remote system.  The name ~/.local/share sounds like they are network shares too.

Comment: These are real files, no symbolic links. I haven't found anything related to the above location using mount. Then, I executed the command given in the answer of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem, which yields to 'ext4'. After that I have shutdown my network connection (LAN, WLAN) and removed all unnecessary devices attached to my machine. No success. The described problem is still there. Shouldn't this eliminate the possibility of a network share?

Comment: Sounds like it, sorry I am out of ideas

Comment: I am still very grateful for your help! I appreciate it.

Comment: what are the UID and GID of `nobody` on your system? What does `id nobody` say?

Comment: @ikkachu the commands yield to: uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)

Comment: @DavidScholz, right, related to Marcus's answer, I wondered if the UID/GID of `nobody` was overly large, but 65534 still fits in 16 bits. And now that I rechecked the man page for `stat()`, it only mentions the "value too large" (EOVERFLOW) error for the file size anyway. But it can't really be the file size if just changing the owner fixed it... If you happen to have any of those dirs left, can you run `strace` on `rm` when trying to remove them, and see where the EOVERFLOW comes from?

Comment: From the strace outputs, the difference between `chown` and `chown -R` seems to be that the latter tries to open the directory for reading, before actually changing the owner. Makes sense, it needs to read the dir to recurse anyway. But why would it not be allowed to read the dir? As root? If your other tools can?? You don't have SELinux, do you? Containers? The immutable/append-only flags from `chattr` can block root, but they shouldn't affect _reading_.

Comment: @ikkachu Sadly, I removed them all (after changing the ownership manually). I am on Linux Manjaro 5.13.9-2 (which should be the newest). I've executed all of the above as root. I use docker, but no containers are running at the moment (the docker deamon is shutdown as well). The first part of the path (5e5a7b41-3df4-4b2f-b7ac-f57d09ed1823) reminds me of the auto-generated uuid of a docker container if no name was provided (or volume?). Thus, this could be the right track as well. Nevertheless, even if it was docker, shouldn't root be still able to remove directories?

Comment: @DavidScholz, I don't actually know much about containers. I understand there's some functionality for UID mapping which sounds like it could be related, maybe, but really I was mostly just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

Without more debugging¹, it's impossible to know for sure, but this sure looks like the stat/stat64 problem Linux had² (and still has).

Basically, there's the `fstat` syscall used to query things like "is this file a directory?" (which is very important to know if you're trying to recursively delete things), "is it a symlink?", "What's its size?".

And that last point's exactly where the fun begins: That syscall takes a pointer to a `struct stat`, which contains fields for all these kinds of information. And originally, the file size integer was 32 bit. Now, a file can be larger than that. So, there needed to be a new call that could give you that information as 64 bit number.

Now, what to do when you used the 32 bit stat variant on a file larger than what the 32 bit variable could hold? Clearly, there needed to be an error condition, so that you'd not accidentally think a 65 GB file was only 1 GB in size. And that error, when passed to `error`/`strerror`/`perror` prints exactly the error message you're seeing.

Of course, the same mechanism applies when other parts of the file stat don't fit in the type you want to return (or when the maximum page count is exceeded, and probably a couple other cases, too).

So, now comes the interesting part: it's very unlikely your relatively modern

> /usr/bin/rm: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=5d1d8b77d21f9362855e93f8cff5fc685127a26f, for GNU/Linux 4.4.0, stripped

is using the *old* `fstat[at]` system call. You can try:

```bsh
cd /tmp
touch base
strace -o log.strace -e /stat rm base
grep '"base"' log.strace
```

should *probably* yield calls to `newfstatat`, which definitely deals with 64 bit numbers.

So, equipped with this knowledge, we now try to delete one of your weird directories:

```bsh
strace -o /tmp/log.strace rm -r /path/to/one/single_one/of/the/undeletable_directories
```

and scroll to the bottom of the log: There's going to be a few lines of calls needed to print the error message, but above that should be a call that yielded `EOVERFLOW` (hint: search for that string!). My hypothesis is that this is *not* a usual stat call, but quite possibly an `openat` call or something that fails for a different reason.

---

¹ I'd run `gdb --args rm /path/to/weirddirectory`, set a breakpoint on any call to `error`, and if that doesn't work, any call to `write`.

² There's even a Coreutils [FAQ entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Tar-created-a-Large-File-but-I-can_0027t-remove-it_002e), [archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html), since I don't trust the FSF to run dependable infrastructure forever

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! It introduces a new debugging technique which I haven't known yet. It seems that you are correct, there is indeed a syscall to 'openat' that fails. I did the same tracing using the 'chown -R' and 'chown' and compared the output and it was nearly identical. However, plain 'chown' succeeds while 'chown -R' did not. Chown the first directory, then chown its subdirectory succeeds as well, thus I've compared the traces and I posted the result in my answer. Does this tell you something? I've ended up chowning manually due to time constraints.

Comment: Great answer... Btw, @MarcusMueller, I heartily endorse your profile quote about two days in a lab versus one hour reading... :)

Answer (score -1):

Please consider that you might be traversing soft links in the recursive path.

Suggesting to try:

```
 chown -L -R me:me pathToSecondWeirdDirectory
```

It is possible to delete traversing symbolic link with `find` command

```
 find -L <target dir1> <target dir2> ... -delete
```

Comment: I would be very wary of using this until you understand where the links are pointing.  As root you could really do some significant damage.

Comment: Sadly, this is not a problem with symbolic links, thus your suggested method does not work.

Comment: Why do you think it would have anything to do with symlinks?